# React-native : how to get coordinates and delta of visible area in MapView component

Tags: javascript, components, coordinates, react-native

Say I have a map defined in react native this way :

```
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, position: 'relative'}}>
                <MapView
                    style={styles.map}
                    showsUserLocation={this.state.showsUserLocation}
                    region={{
                        latitude: 48.8534100,
                        longitude: 2.3378000,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.12,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.065
                    }}
                    onRegionChangeComplete={
                        () => {
                            // How to retrieve coordinates and Delta when user moves the map
                            console.log(this.region);
                        }
                    } />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

How to retrieve the coordinates and Delta when the user moves on the map ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do this...

In your render() function, set onRegionChangeComplete like this:

```
onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}
```

Then define the callback function in your component, e.g. below the render() function:

```
onRegionChangeComplete: function(region) {
    console.log(region.longitude);
    console.log(region.latitude);
}
```